# Vue3 - Bind multiple named v-model dynamically

Tags: vue.js, vuejs3, v-model

I am currently building a tool with Vue3 that allow user for custom plugin building. In their respective plugin, user can define a set of settings and define which component should render the setting. Some of these rendering components might have [multiple v-model bindings](https://vuejs.org/guide/components/v-model.html#multiple-v-model-bindings) and their name can be different depending on the component. I am currently able to build a plugin setting dynamically with a main JS object but I have no idea how to bind a **named** `v-model` dynamically.

I tried to pass the additional models to the `v-bind` attribute and I am able to get the value but since no `v-model` is assigned to these properties I am not able to get incoming changes from the child component.

Is there a way to add dynamic named v-model in **MainRenderer.vue** to have the relevant named model assigned to the right components.

When I hard coded the v-model binding as below, I have the desired behavior for my main component. But since the component are various and custom, this solution won't work in production.

```
<component 
    v-for="field in formFields" 
    :is="field.component" 
    v-model="field.models.modelValue"
    v-model:foo="field.models.foo"
    v-model:foo="field.models.bar"
    v-bind="field.props"
></component>
```

I created a lighter version of this issue with the 4 following files to describe the issue. The customization is managed via the `fields` object in **App.vue**

[**DEMO ON PLAY VUEJS**](https://play.vuejs.org/#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)

**App.vue**

```js
<template>
    <MainRenderer :form-fields="fields" :action="action">
      Submit
    </MainRenderer>
    <div>{{foo}} - {{inputFoo}}</div>
    <div>{{bar}} - {{inputBar}}</div>
</template>

<script lang="ts" setup>
import { ref, reactive, shallowRef } from 'vue'
import MainRenderer, { FormField } from './MainRenderer.vue'
import Foo from './Foo.vue'
import Bar from './Bar.vue'

const inputFoo = ref('fooValue')
const inputBar = ref('barValue')
const foo = ref(false)
const bar = ref(false)

const fields: FormField[] = reactive([
    {
        name: "Foo - String Input Field",
        model: shallowRef(inputFoo),
        models: { modelValue: inputFoo, foo: foo },
        props: { class: 'dummy-class', placeholder: "Input A" },
        component: Foo
    },
    {
        name: "Bar - Multi Item Input Field",
        model: shallowRef(inputBar),
        models: { modelValue: inputBar, bar: bar },
        props: { class: 'dummy-class', 'v-model:foo':shallowRef(bar) },
        component: Bar
    },
])


const action = async function () {
    console.log(fields)
}
</script>
```

**MainRenderer.vue**

```js
<template>
    <form @submit.prevent="action">
        <div v-for="field in formFields">
            <component :is="field.component" v-bind="field.props" v-model="field.model"></component>
        </div>
        <button type="submit">
            <slot></slot>
        </button>
    </form>
</template>

<script lang="ts">
import { Ref, defineComponent, PropType, Component } from 'vue';
import Foo from './Foo.vue'
import Bar from './Foo.vue'

export interface FormField {
    name: String
    props: Object
    component: Component
    model: Ref
    models: Object
}

export default defineComponent({
    components: { Foo, Bar },
    props: {
        formFields: {
            type: Array as PropType<Array<FormField>>
        },
        action: {
            type: Function as PropType<() => Promise<any>>
        }
    }
})
</script>
```

**Foo.vue**

```js
<template>
    <input :name="name" v-model="value">
</template>

<script lang="ts">
import { defineComponent } from 'vue'

export default defineComponent({
    props: {
        name: String,
        modelValue: String,
        foo: Boolean
    },
    watch: {
        modelValue: function () {
            const newFooValue = (typeof this.modelValue === 'number') // Example
            this.$emit('update:foo', newFooValue)
        }
    },
    computed: {
        value: {
            get() {
                return this.modelValue
            },
            set(v: string) {
                return this.$emit('update:modelValue', v)
            }
        }
    }
})
</script>
```

**Bar.vue**

```js
<template>
    <input :name="name" v-model="value">
</template>

<script lang="ts">
import { defineComponent } from 'vue'

export default defineComponent({
    props: {
        name: String,
        modelValue: String,
        bar: Boolean
    },
    watch: {
        modelValue: function () {
            const newBarValue = this.modelValue.charAt(0) === 'B'
            this.$emit('update:bar', newBarValue)
        }
    },
    computed: {
        value: {
            get() {
                return this.modelValue
            },
            set(v: string) {
                return this.$emit('update:modelValue', v)
            }
        }
    }
})
</script>
```

PS: I know from the example above, the use of multiple v-model seems unnecessary but I tried to avoid copy/paste a lot of 'out-of-scope' code.

Answer (score 1):

You can build your own `v-model` like this:

```html
<!-- parent component -->
<template>
<component :is="field.component" v-bind="field.props" @updateValue="onUpdateValue"></component>
</template>

<script lang="ts" setup>
function onUpdateValue(field: string, value: any){
  field.models[field] = value
}
</script>
```

```html
<!-- child component -->
<template>
<input :value="somePropsField" @input="$emit('updateValue', 'somePropsField', $event)"></input>
</template>
```

In the child component, you emit an event called `updateValue` with a field name to update, and the value of that field. And in the parent component, you listen to that event and update the data accordingly

Comment: The solution works fine but is not really adapted since child component might be a custom user component. I wish to avoid user diving into $emits so I can render the form programmatically without too much user interaction

Comment: @Waligoo Let's imagine you can hard code the v-model binding as in question. But the child component still needs manually emit an event to make it work, right?

Answer (score 0):

To whoever encounters the same need, you can add bindings for `:<REF_NAME>` and `onUpdate:<REF_NAME>`. The parent component will be in control of the child component model, it might not be the cleanest way to achieve it but it achieve the purpose.

I link an updated [DEMO](https://play.vuejs.org/#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) if needed

```
<script lang="ts" setup>
import { ref, reactive, shallowRef } from 'vue'
import MainRenderer, { FormField } from './MainRenderer.vue'
import Foo from './Foo.vue'
import Bar from './Bar.vue'


function defineNamedModel(name: string, model: Ref){
    // A generic function to avoid repeating code
    let binding = `:${name}`
    let updateCallback = `onUpdate:${name}` 
    return {
        [binding]: model,
        [updateCallback]:((v: any) => model.value = v)
    }
}

const inputFoo = ref('fooValue')
const inputBar = ref('barValue')
const foo = ref(false)
const bar = ref(false)

const fields: FormField[] = reactive([
    {
        name: "Foo - String Input Field",
        model: shallowRef(inputFoo),
        props: { class: 'dummy-class', placeholder: "Input A" },
        component: Foo
    },
    {
        name: "Bar - Multi Item Input Field",
        model: shallowRef(inputBar),
        props: { class: 'dummy-class', ...defineNamedModel('bar', bar)},
        component: Bar
    },
])


const action = async function () {
    console.log(fields)
}
</script>
```